# Textbox 'popup' display on mouseover/hover for CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html `td` element with text inside.  I want it so you can hover over that element, and display a textbox on top of the active page/element explaining what that td tag's content means.  Some kind of elaboration. Like the `<abbr>` tag.

Can this be done in CSS or Javascript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is possible with CSS, also with javascript.  Create a table with an element:

```
<table>
<tr><td>
    <a href="#">Info
        <div class="tooltipcontainer">
            <div class="tooltip">Here some info</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
/* Container is necessary because td cannot be positioned relative */
td .tooltipcontainer {
    position: relative;
}
td .tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    /* More positioning, heigh, width, etc */
}
td a:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

When you hover over 'Info' it will show the text in the div with class='tooltip'.  JavaScript (for example any jQuery tooltip plugin) has solutions with more options.

Comment: This would be better for usability tbh

Comment: Thank you. This was the kind of CSS solution I was looking for. I do think however the Javascript solution has more benefits.

Answer (score 3):

Example markup..

```
<td id="1">..</td>
<td id="2">..</td>
<td id="thisiswhatiwanttohaveahover"><div class="tooltip hidden"></div></td>
```

CSS Style

```
.visible {
  display:block;
}

.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

you can

```
$('#thisiswhatiwanttohaveahover').hover(function() {
  if ($(this + ' .tooltip').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $(this + ' .tooltip').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this + ' .tooltip').addClass('visible');
  }
  if ($(this + ' .tooltip').hasClass('visible')) {
    $(this + ' .tooltip').removeClass('visible');
    $(this + ' .tooltip').addClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Tooltip JS](http://ajaxian.com/archives/tooltipjs-creating-simple-tooltips) before. It worked really well and I think it'd be beneficial to you.